# Vuejs application maintaining cache when the user leaves the open tab for 1-2 days

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

If I open the vuejs application and leaves that tab for 1-2 days then the application is maintaining the cache so how do i remove the cache and one more thing the cache will remove after doing the hard reload of page.

Is there any way to remove the cache in the vuejs application without doing the hard reload at the code level

Comment: What did you do already? Can you use the usual HTTP cache expiration stuff?